# The bounded complex of a polyhedral decomposition

Tags: convex-geometry, polyhedra, cw-complexes

Let $\mathscr{P}$ be a polyhedral decomposition of a real vector space $V$.  By that I mean that $\mathscr{P}$ is a finite set of polyhedra in $V$ satisfying the following three properties:

1. The union of the polyhedra in $\mathscr{P}$ is equal to $V$.
2. If $P\in \mathscr{P}$ and $Q$ is a face of $P$, then $Q\in\mathcal{P}$.
3. If $P,Q\in\mathscr{P}$, then $P\cap Q$ is a (possibly empty) face of both $P$ and $Q$.

Question:  Is the union of the bounded elements of $\mathscr{P}$ contractible?

If $\mathscr{P}$ consists of the set of faces of an essential hyperplane arrangement, then a positive answer is stated in Exercise 1.7.a of Stanley's lecture notes [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis6100/sp06stanley.pdf](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis6100/sp06stanley.pdf), though I don't know the reference for a proof.  Note that, when $\mathscr{P}$ does not come from a hyperplane arrangement, then the bounded complex need not be pure.

Comment: Thanks to Dane Miyata for pointing out that the statement in Stanley's notes is proved in Theorem Theorem 4.5.7(i) of the book Oriented Matroids.  Still, I'd like to know what happens when $\mathscr{P}$ does not come from a hyperplane arrangement!

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is a relatively straightforward proof for that exercise from Stanley using discrete Morse theory. Perhaps discrete Morse theory can also be applied to the situation you are interested in.

Comment: What are the rules for polyhedra? Is V a polyhedral decomposition of itself into one part?

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks for the suggestion!  I have thought about that a little bit, but was deterred by the fact that discrete Morse theory is usually applied to simplicial complexes rather than to polyhedral complexes.

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon Touché.  I guess I would like to assume that my decomposition contains at least one vertex.

Comment: I believe Pavel Galashin is the person who once showed me the argument using discrete Morse theory. You could possibly try contacting him.

Comment: @NicholasProudfoot Well then I will draw a capacitor diagram consisting of two vertices each with three outgoing rays; an infinite strip separates the two vertices.

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon That would be no good because some of the rays would be contained in the strip, but would not be faces of the strip.  In particular, condition 3 would fail.

Comment: @NicholasProudfoot Ok, so I'm not allowed to subdivide faces.  Are non-convex polyhedra allowed?  I could point the parallel rays away from each other and get an hourglass-type separation between the vertices.

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon By "polyhedron" I mean an intersection of finitely many closed half-spaces.  In particular, it is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below I construct a deformation retract of $V$ onto the bounded sub-complex of $\mathscr P$, proving that the latter is contractible.

For a polyhedral complex $\mathscr P$ resp. a polyhedron $P\in\mathscr P$ I write $\mathscr P^b\subseteq\mathscr P$ resp. $P^b\subseteq P$ for its bounded sub-complex.
Also, by *a retract* of a polyhedron $P$ (or polyhedral complex $\mathscr P$) I mean a [strong deformation retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)) $\phi_P: P\times[0,1]\to P^b$ from $P$ onto $P^b\subseteq P$.
Such clearly exist if $P$ is bounded (just use the identity) or if $P$ is a half-infinite edge. But below I explain how to define such for all polyhedra, in such a way that they are compatible on their boundaries and so can be glued together to form a retract for all of $\mathscr P$. The latter is therefore homotopy equivalent to $\bigcup_{P\in\mathscr P} P=V$, hence contractible.

*Proof.*

- Each $P\in\mathscr P$ can be written as $P=P^b+C_P$, where $C_P$ is the [recession cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recession_cone) of $P$. Fix a choice of *generalized barycentric coordinates* (e.g. mean value coordinates, Wachspress coordinates, ...), i.e. for each point $x\in P$ we have a canonical decomposition $x=x_b+x_C$ with $x_b\in P^b$ and $x_C\in C_P$ that only depends on the shape of $P$ and the location of $x$ relative to it (see also below). Then set $\phi_P(x,t):=x_b+(1-t)x_C$.
- For $P,Q\in\mathscr P$ the above definition ensures that $\phi_P(x,t)=\phi_Q(x,t)$ for all $x\in P\cap Q$, so that we can extend the retract to all of $\mathscr P$.

$\square$

---

**Some notes on "the canonical choice"**

As aluded to in the comments, it is sufficient to construct a section $s_P:P\to P^b\times C_P$  for the projection

$$\pi_P:P^b\times C_P\to P,(x_b,x_C)\mapsto x_b+x_C,$$

(i.e., $\pi_P\circ s_P=\mathrm{id}_P$) that matches with prescribed sections $s_\sigma:\sigma\to\sigma^b\times C_\sigma$ on the faces $\sigma\subseteq P$. Here is one idea for how to do this.

The recession cones of polyhedra in $\mathscr P$ form a full fan $\mathscr F:=\{C_P\mid P\in\mathscr P\}$ of $V$. For each cone $C_P\in\mathscr F$ choose a ray $r_P\subseteq C_P$.
Now, for a point $x\in P$ let $x_b'$ be the intersection of $\partial P$ with the translated and inverted ray $-r_P+x$ (which exists since the linearity space of $C_P$ is empty). In particular, $x_b'$ is in some face $\sigma\subseteq \partial P$. Then set $x_b:=s_\sigma(x_b')$ and $x_C:= x-x_b$.

Comment: This looks really promising!  I'm not familiar with generalized barycentric coordinates, and with just a little googling I haven't been able to find your statement about the canonical decomposition anywhere.  Do you have a reference that I can look at?

Comment: Or perhaps you were asking about the decomposition $x=x_b + x_C$. Again, it is not the exact setting here, but see ["A geometric construction of coordinates for convex polyhedra using polar duals"](http://www.geometry.caltech.edu/pubs/JSWD05.pdf). Basically you have a surjective map $\pi: P^b\times C\to P, (x_b,x_C)\mapsto x_b +x_C$ and barycentric coordinates are some section $s:P\to P^b\times C$ (i.e. $\pi\circ s=\mathrm{id}_P$), which can be constructed in many ways (which should not be too hard), and we don't care about the exact definition, but just that there is one.

Comment: Indeed, I have no problem with the decomposition of P as the bounded complex plus a cone; what I was asking about was the section s.  The needed statement is not just that there is a section, but that it is canonical enough that everything will glue together nicely.

Comment: @Nicholas You are right that some details need to be figured out. But I hope you agree that they seem reasonable. The source above gives a good point to start for constructing a canonical choice. But you can also avoid "canonical enough": given the section on the boundary of a polyhedron, it should not be hard to extend it in just *some way* to the full polyhedron using that all involved sets are contractible. Given that, you can define the section for $\mathscr P$ from the lower dimensional faces upwards.

Comment: Yes, I agree!  The fundamental problem is to assume that we have a section on every proper face of a single polyhedron (compatible on intersections) and then to extend to the interior.  I will take a close look at the reference that you sent and see if I can figure out how to do that.

Comment: @NicholasProudfoot I updated the answer with some more concrete idea for how to construct a section. There are still details to be checked ($x_C\in C_P$ and continuity), but it is a start.

Comment: I don't quite understand this construction.  Suppose for example that $P = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | x\geq 0, y\geq 0, x+y \geq 1\}$, and $x=(1,1)$.  Then, depending on your choice of $r$, $x_b$ could be any element of $P^b$.  You really want to fix an $r$ for each polyhedron, but an element $r$ that is in the recession cone for $P$ will not be in the recession cone for every face of $P$.  Choosing a different $r$ when you pass to a face will introduce discontinuity.

Comment: Ah, maybe now I understand.  As discussed in your second comment, it's enough to show that, given a single polyhedron $P$ and a retraction from the boundary of $P$ to its bounded complex, we can extend this to a retraction from $P$ to its bounded complex.  But, to do that, it's enough to find a retraction from $P$ to its boundary.  And this can be done by choosing any element of the relative interior of the recession cone of $P$ and applying the construction in your "some notes" addendum.  Perhaps that does it!

Comment: I guess that last part only works if $P$ has the same dimension as its recession cone.  Otherwise the argument needs to be modified a little bit, but I think it can be done.

Comment: @Nicholas You are right that the construction came with potential discontinuities if the recession cone is not full-dimensional and if the choice of ray in the interior disagrees with the choice of ray on a face with the same cone. I updated the answer to make a choice of ray for each type of recession cone in advance. Was this the problem that you pointed to?

Comment: Yes, that sounds good to me!  I think there is an even simpler and more general statement.  Start with the following Lemma:  Any unbounded polyhedron with at least one vertex strongly deformation retracts onto its boundary.  (If the recession cone is full dimensional, your construction is a proof.  If not, it can be tweaked.)  Corollary:  Let $\mathscr{P}$ be a connected polyhedral complex with at least one vertex.  Then $\mathscr{P}$ strongly deformation retracts onto its bounded complex.  Proof:  Use the lemma to do one maximal unbounded polyhedron at a time, until only bounded faces remain.